# Unable to install Ubuntu - bootable USB

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, live-usb, iso

I had an old laptop, installed Ubuntu (don't remember version) on it with bootable usb. Nothing went wrong. However I changed the old laptop with a new one (mostly gaming reasons) and Ubuntu is simply failing to install. I tried 12.04, but instead of the "install ALONGSIDE windows 7" (which I did on my previous laptop), it gave me "Install INSIDE windows 7" which will open a WUBI (the thing I wanted to avoid). After trying several times with older versions (11.04 gave me only replace and "other options" which I'm not sure how to use it and I would like to avoid) I finally gave up and tried with WUBI....only to see it won't work, with any version. It gaves me the "NoneType object has no attribuite get_info" error, with every iso I tried from 12.04 to 13.10 (downloaded from mirrors and torrents too!).

Can anyone provide me an iso with the install alongside thing? Or at least help me? I'm not familiar with shrinking, resising and doing magic with partitions so I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

It's curious that the installation process won't allow you to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, but it suggest you to install inside it. 
First of all, sorry if my question will seem completely idiot, did you start your pc from the live usb? Because wubi invocation seems strange, unless you've started it from windows itself. And ... if instead of using an usb-key, you boot from an ubuntu live CD/DVD? Have you already tried? And it gives you the same answer?

With regard to "other options", why are you so scared? Obviously you must pay attention when choosing HDU and partitioning it, but it's not so difficult, imho.

Anyway, my first suggestion is to burn a DVD from Ubuntu ISO and try installing from there: if your pc haven't any dvd burner you probably can ask to your friends for an usb one.

Cheers and merry Christmas!

Silvia

Comment: Well I did not open WUBI, I sucessfully booted Ubuntu from an USB, it worked when I selected "try it" and everything was perfect. However when I tried to install it, it gave me 3 options, "others", "replace windows 7" and "install inside". I selected install inside and it restarted the pc and booted windows and as it opened, there was an automagically opened WUBI (probably frolm the mounted iso on the usb), run it but after the install it gave me an error and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use bootable USB drive than Wubi installer,
Create a bootable USB from iso file using [poweriso](http://www.poweriso.com/)

select *tools > make bootable USB* in power iso

that will create a bootable USB for any version of ubuntu.

Restarting your system should give you an prompt for installing Ubuntu

Comment: I used pendrive to make my bootable USB as I used it previously so it gained my trust. Anyway my problem is that no iso gives me the "install alongside windows", but install inside it (which restarts my pc, boots windows and automatically opens a WUBI after windows started) or use the "other" which as I said don't want to mess with or to replace windows 7 (which I don't want as some of my games won't run on Ubuntu)